# Two Dependent Variables Prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, statsmodels

I have a dataset which has multiple columns. The columns include time, location, wind speed, and wind direction (captured at different time snapshots). I want to predict wind speed and wind direction using a linear regression algorithm. I tried finding examples for it but I could not find an example where two variables are predicted using two or more independent variables.

I plan to do it in python. If any existing library like scikit-learn could be used for it, please give an example for the code because I could not find it.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Show what you have tried please.  There are several examples on internet: [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-output-regression-models-with-python/)

Comment: You can train two different Linear regression model, one foe wind speed and one for wind direction

Comment: Can I get both using one linear regression model?

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat So far, I was just searching for an existing model that has been implemented in Python and I can use it for my problem.

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat Thank you for your help. I went through the tutorial link you shared. I am new to machine learning. So, can you please explain how can I divide into train and test sets the dataset I mentioned with its columns? I see that all the examples in that tutorial use make_regression to create a dataset and not divide the dataset into train and test samples.